# K nearest neighbours algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, image, tkinter, clustering

Here is a project that I worked on for a few days in June 2020. Since the algorithm is extremely slow, I looked into methods in order to parallelize operations but did not obtain any satisfactory answers.

[https://github.com/aaronjohnsabu1999/tk2NN](https://github.com/aaronjohnsabu1999/tk2NN/tree/7634dfe7d9ac6d6921d805dfd27daefe42864beb)

The project is a Tkinter implementation of the k-Nearest Neighbor (kNN) algorithm which randomly chooses points and colors based on the user's input for the number of points, the number of labels and the type of distance (Euclidean or Manhattan).

Please suggest anything ranging from how to make the algorithm faster to how to make the environment more attractive

Here is the [script](https://github.com/aaronjohnsabu1999/tk2NN/blob/master/main.py) for the project:

```
import time
from   PIL       import Image
from   colour    import Color
from   random    import random, randint
from   general   import colorPicker, generatePoints
from   tkinter   import *
from   canvasDev import canvasDetermine

HEIGHT     = 520
WIDTH      = 540

BORDER_XL  =  15
BORDER_YL  =  15
BORDER_XH  = 415
BORDER_YH  = 415
numLabels  =   3
numPoints  =   9
resolution =   1
k          =   1

def clearPointSpace(event):
    global selectPoints
    selectPoints = []
    pointSpace.delete(ALL)

def updateInput(event):
    global numLabels, numPoints, selectPoints, k
    nLChange = False
    nPChange = False
    nKChange = False
    try:
        nLChange  = not (numLabels == int(FNumL.get()))
        numLabels = int(FNumL.get())
    except Exception:
        pass
    try:
        nPChange  = not (numPoints == int(FNumP.get()))
        numPoints = int(FNumP.get())
    except Exception:
        pass
    try:
        nKChange  = not (k == int(FKSet.get()))
        k         = int(FKSet.get())
    except Exception:
        pass
    FNumL.delete(0, END)
    FNumP.delete(0, END)
    FKSet.delete(0, END)
    FNumL.insert(0, str(numLabels))
    FNumP.insert(0, str(numPoints))
    FKSet.insert(0, str(k))
    if nLChange or nPChange:
        selectPoints = generatePoints(BORDER_XH - BORDER_XL, BORDER_YH - BORDER_YL, numLabels, numPoints)
    updatePointSpace()

def bindButtons():
    pointSpace.delete("all")
    updatePointSpace()

def updatePointSpace():
    (canvas, error) = canvasDetermine(k, distType.get(), BORDER_XH - BORDER_XL, BORDER_YH - BORDER_YL, selectPoints)
    colors          = colorPicker(selectPoints)

    for y in range(resolution, BORDER_YH - BORDER_YL + resolution, resolution*2):
        for x in range(resolution, BORDER_XH - BORDER_XL + resolution, resolution*2):
            try:
                color = colors[canvas[y][x]]
            except Exception:
                color = Color("#000000")
            color.saturation = (color.saturation + 1.0)/2.0
            pointSpace.create_rectangle(x - resolution, y - resolution, x + resolution, y + resolution, fill = color)
    for point in selectPoints:
        pointX, pointY = point[0]
        pointSpace.create_rectangle(pointX - resolution*2, pointY - resolution*2, pointX + resolution*2, pointY + resolution*2, fill = colors[point[1]])

base = Tk()
base.resizable(width = False, height = False)
base.title("tk2NN")
base.configure(bg = 'grey')
base.geometry(str(WIDTH) + "x" + str(HEIGHT))

distType = IntVar()
distType.set(1)

selectPoints = generatePoints(BORDER_XH - BORDER_XL, BORDER_YH - BORDER_YL, numLabels, numPoints)

background_image = PhotoImage(file = './bg.png')
background_label = Label(base, image = background_image)
background_label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

pointSpace = Canvas(base, width = BORDER_XH - BORDER_XL, height = BORDER_YH - BORDER_YL, borderwidth = 4, relief = SUNKEN, background = 'black', cursor = 'dot')
pointSpace.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = (BORDER_XL, 5), pady = (BORDER_YL, 5))
pointSpace.bind("<Button-2>",  clearPointSpace)

updatePointSpace()

typeSpace = Frame(base)
typeSpace.grid(row = 0, column = 3, rowspan = 2, pady = (5, 5))
chooseEu  = Radiobutton(typeSpace, text = "Euclidean", variable = distType, value = 1, command = bindButtons)
chooseEu.pack(anchor = W)
chooseMh  = Radiobutton(typeSpace, text = "Manhattan", variable = distType, value = 2, command = bindButtons)
chooseMh.pack(anchor = E)

def clear_placeholder(event, e):
    inVal =  e.get()
    if not isinstance(inVal, int):
        e.delete(0, END)

def add_placeholder(event, e, ph):
    inVal = e.get()
    try:
        inVal = int(inVal)
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, inVal)
    except Exception:
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, ph)        

labelSpace = Frame(base)
labelSpace.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 25)
FNumL = Entry (labelSpace, bg = 'white', bd = 3, width = 12)
FNumP = Entry (labelSpace, bg = 'white', bd = 3, width = 12)
FKSet = Entry (labelSpace, bg = 'white', bd = 3, width = 7)
UpdtB = Button(labelSpace, bg = '#9999FF', activebackground = '#444499', bd = 3, text = "Update", padx = 3)
FNumL.insert(0, "Num of Labels")
FNumP.insert(0, "Num of Points")
FKSet.insert(0, "k-level")
FNumL.pack(side = LEFT)
FNumP.pack(side = LEFT)
FKSet.pack(side = LEFT)
UpdtB.pack(side = LEFT)
FNumL.bind("<FocusIn>",  lambda event: clear_placeholder(event, FNumL))
FNumP.bind("<FocusIn>",  lambda event: clear_placeholder(event, FNumP))
FKSet.bind("<FocusIn>",  lambda event: clear_placeholder(event, FKSet))
FNumL.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: add_placeholder(event, FNumL, "Num of Labels"))
FNumP.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: add_placeholder(event, FNumP, "Num of Points"))
FKSet.bind("<FocusOut>", lambda event: add_placeholder(event, FKSet, "k-level"))
FNumL.bind("<Return>",   updateInput)
UpdtB.bind("<Button-1>", updateInput)

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, include a description of what the code does. Also title should contain the goal accomplished by the code, not your concerns about it. And if you believe that reviewers will "need to see the whole script", then include the whole script in your question. Questions are supposed to be self-contained. And if you think there's something about the code that needs explanation, please include the explanation. In current state, your question is going to be "look-and-leave" for many potential reviewers, me including. Not bad enough to vote to close, not good enough to even upvote...

Comment: @slepic thanks for the comments. I do wish to post the whole code but it is enormous, at least for the scale of SE questions. I'll do it anyway but let me know if it is huge. I'll reduce it in that case

Comment: Not long at all. I have yet modified the title. Upvoting now...

Comment: The current code is size-wise no problem at all. Welcome to Code Review!